# Session management

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am developing an case management application.I have created login page and landing page other pages as well.
i have used the spring mvc 4,oracle database.

A used logged into the application and then went to admin page.copy the admin page url  ,logout from the application.when the user directly copy and paste the admin page url into another user user he is able to open that page.how can i restrict the user. when user perform any crud operation how can validate user's credentials every time.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring framework, the best practice case you can implement is to integrate [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

Regarding the session handling within your system, you might use JWT tokens which allows you to control the user flow easily. You can read [this](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java) complete tutorial.